# The importance of generating series

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, generating-functions

What follows is a very nebulous question. I just seek for some help in understanding a "technique" which has proven itself very powerful.

I noticed that very often generating series appear in Algebraic Geometry. I am wondering: why can they be a so powerful tool? What is their secret?

What is actually happening when we have computed some numbers, enumerative invariants, classes in a Grothendieck ring... whatever data we are interested in, and we put them all together in a generating series?

*Example*. Think about [Witten's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witten_conjecture). One can compute Gromov-Witten invariants
$$\int_{\overline M_{g,n}}\psi_1^{a_1}\cup\dots\cup\psi_n^{a_n}$$ and put them all together in the generating series
$$F_g=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{a_1,\dots,a_n} \Big(\int_{\overline M_{g,n}}\psi_1^{a_1}\cup\dots\cup\psi_n^{a_n}\Big)t_{a_1}\dots t_{a_n}.$$
Not yet satisfied, one takes the generating series over all genera $F=\sum_g F_gh^{2g-2}$ and then the exponential $e^F$ of $F$. Witten's conjecture is equivalent to $L_ne^F=0$ for all $n$, where $L_n$ are certain differential operators.

I am sorry for the vagueness of the above. Any insight and concrete example is very welcome.

Comment: this seems like a good question for Mathoverflow.

Comment: Are you familiar with the uses of elementary generating functions, like when you take the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers or something?

Comment: I am not familiar at all with that. I only read once that putting the FIbonacci numbers in a series one can view their sequence as a differential equation (as the derivative of a power series is a "switched" power series). But no, I am not used to generating series.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with algebraic geometry. Generating functions is a useful machine to work with any large collection of numbers satisfying some recurrence relation(s).

Comment: @GrigoryM: sure, that is why I slightly modified the title, when I asked this question on MO (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142743/the-importance-of-generating-series-in-algebraic-geometry).